# Does the word "indeed" have a condescending or patronizing connotation?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, connotation

I often hear people use the word "indeed" in a response to someone sharing an idea and suggesting the fact that they already knew or thought about the idea. Almost as a substitute to "Obviously", but in a more passive way. Therefore suggesting that they are already miles ahead and causing that condescending tone.

Its translation in french on the other hand has a more polite connotation. It suggests an agreement and often the idea that the receiver didn't think about it beforehand.

I'm not a native english speaker and I would like to avoid conflicts and clarify if this word has a condescending meaning in its popular use.

Comment: It is definitely not an informal word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is "yes", it sounds somewhat ......... *British!*  or maybe *pretentious*.

I would say, **use with care**, if you are not a familiar native speaker.

I use it a lot, but I'm able to put it over as:

- "scientific"
- "engineering-oriented"
- "in agreement with" the other speaker .. "You're right, I'll add detail on that"

**But** if you want to, it's easy to use it as outright

- supercilious
- "over-educated" sounding
- superiority, more-posh-than-you feeling

"I'm not a native english speaker..." Alternatives that capture only the positive side are *"Quite right, Steve. Furthermore..."* or *"Sure! In fact, ..."*

So indeed - take care!

Comment: It does sound british. I can almost hear Sherlock answering this to one of Watson's observations "Elementary/Indeed my dear watson [...]". I, more than often, tend to use alternatives similar to those you suggested. I wanted to see if I was avoiding this word for nothing or if my fears were well-founded. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed. Your fears were founded well.

Comment: I'd disagree that it's inherently poncey - but +1 for "use with care".